# “C'est” in passé composé

Tags: pronoms, passé-composé, élision

I am learning *passé composé*, and I am not exactly sure what is the equivalent of “*c'est*” in this past tense?

First, I though that I should do:
“*c'a été*”, as for *être* the auxiliary is *avoir* and the the participle is *été*, however, I was told, this is not correct…

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In proper speech the use of “*ça*” is to be avoided (in any case it isn't used in present tense with the verb *être*). In *passé composé*, formal register, “ce” and “a été” are the parts to be joined together. The result is “ç'a été”. Lest the combination of letters *c* and *a* be pronounced */ka/*, and even though an apostrophe is there, the letter *c* is turned into *ç*, yielding unambiguously */sa/*. The same occurs, for example, when the auxiliary is in imperfect or future tense: “*ç'avait été*”, “*ç'aura été*”.

In ordinary speech people often use *ça* (with past or future tenses) instead of *ce*, despite the fact that it may take longer to pronounce: “*ça a été*”, “*ça sera*”. *Ça* is a substitute for the “more correct” *cela*. The latter can be used (just like *ce*) with all tenses.

---

En langage soigné on évite d'écrire « *ça* » (on ne le fait d'ailleurs jamais au présent avec le verbe *être*). Au passé composé dans un registre soigné il faut donc combiner « *ce* » et « *a été* ». Et le résultat est « ç'a été ». La combinaison des lettres *c* et *a* résulte en la prononciation */ka/*, et malgré l'apostrophe on préfère changer le *c* en *ç* pour obtenir */sa/*. Il se passe la même chose, par exemple, lorsque l'auxiliaire est à l'imparfait ou au futur : « ç'avait été », « ç'aura été ».

Dans le langage habituel étonnamment on utilise souvent le pronom *ça* (au passé ou au futur c'est possible) plutôt que *ce*, même si ça devient parfois plus long à prononcer : « ça a été », « ça sera ». Le mot qu'il remplace en « langage correct » est *cela*, qui lui (tout comme *ce*) peut s'employer sans restriction, à tous les temps.

Comment: Des sources, par hasard ?

Answer (score 4):

If "*c'est*" is an elided form of "*ce est*", which is likely the case if you consider the negative is much [more often](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ce%20n%27est%20pas,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,ce%20n%27est%20pas;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas;,c0) "*ce n'est pas*" than "*ça n'est pas*", the *passé composé* should be:

> Ç'a été

as the rule is "*ce*" must be elided here in "*ç'*", the cedilla being there to keep the soft /s/ sound.

If it is an elided form of "*ça est*", that would be:

> Ça a été or even [Ç'a été](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ce%20n%27est%20pas,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,ce%20n%27est%20pas;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas;,c0)

As there is probably no way to make sure what "*c'*" stands for in "*c'est*", both forms should be accepted.

If we compare the [usage trend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7%27a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9,%C3%A7a%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%C3%A7%27a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A7a%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9;,c0) between "*Ç'a été*" and "*Ça a été*", we can see that the former was the most usual one until the mid sixties while the latter, almost unused at the beginning of the nineteenth century slightly overcome the former then strongly impose itself. This trend is likely due to an over-correction caused by the confusion between "ce" and "ça" because of the cedilla. This is unfortunate as "*Ç'a été*" is more literate than the casual, spoken French "*Ça a été*".

---

Si « c'est » est pris comme l'élision de « ce est », ce qui est le cas probable vu la [proportion](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ce%20n%27est%20pas,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,ce%20n%27est%20pas;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A7a%20n%27est%20pas;,c0) de « ce n'est pas » comparé au « ça n'est pas», le passé composé doit être:

> Ç'a été

car la règle est que « ce » doit être élidé en « ç' », la cédille étant là pour conserver le son /s/ .

S'il est pris comme l'élision de « ça est », le passé composé sera :

> Ça a été
>   ou
>   [Ç'a été](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3625)

Comme il n'est probablement pas possible de déterminer de quoi « ç » est l'élision, les deux formes devraient être acceptées.

Si l'on compare l'[évolution](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7%27a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9,%C3%A7a%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,%C3%A7%27a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9;,c0;.t1;,%C3%A7a%20a%20%C3%A9t%C3%A9;,c0) de l'utilisation de « Ç'a été » par rapport à  « Ça a été », on peut constater que la première forme était la plus courante jusqu'au milieu des années soixante alors que la deuxième forme, quasi inexistante au début du XIXe siècle a lentement augmenté jusqu'à rattraper la première puis s'est fortement imposée depuis. Cette tendance est probablement due à une sur-correction causée par la confusion du « ce » en « ça » à cause de la cédille. C'est dommage car « Ç'a été » est plus littéraire que « Ça a été » qui est plus du domaine du langage parlé.

Answer (score 3):

La question est moins évidente qu’elle ne le semble de prime abord. Hélas mes (courtes) recherches se sont avérées infructueuses ; le Grevisse<sup>1</sup> n’évoque pas véritablement le sujet.

Le seul élément probant que je puisse apporter est un « Ç’avait été » de Bernanos, cité dans ledit Grevisse.

> Ç’avait été d’abord de ces petits manquements involontaires qui ressemblent à des distractions. (Bernanos, *Imposture*, p. 218)

La meilleure suggestion qui je puisse faire est donc d’employer « ç’a été », avec une cédille sur le « ç », due au a qui suit malgré l’apostrophe.

---

1. 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §933 3<sup>o</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Tu y étais presque. Le problème est sur le « ça ». On ne peut pas faire l'élision du *a*, même si on ne l'entend pas vraiment en prononçant. Donc « **ça a été** », sans oublier la cédille. On peut aussi utiliser « ceci » ou « cela » à la place de ça.

You've grasped it, the problem is that you can't elide the *a* although it's not usually sounded when speaking. **Ça a été** [saete] or [sa:ete]. And don't forget the cedilla on the *c*.  You could also use "ceci" or "cela" instead of ça.

I would like to add, though, that we would often prefer using "*ce fut*" (passé simple) instead of the *passé composé*.

Comment: À la reflexion, le « c’ » de « c’est » n’est pas un « ça », c’est un « ce ». Pourquoi donc ne pas élider, par conséquent ?

Comment: @Édouard: ça dépend du contexte et du niveau de langue. Grevisse signale « ça est » comme populaire et plus employé en Belgique, désuet en France. De plus pour les puristes « ça »  devant un verbe ne devrait pas être élidé, mais dans le langage parlé il en va tout autrement et on rencontre les deux : « ça a été » et « ç'a été ». Un ngram montre « ça a été » comme beaucoup plus courant.

Comment: @Laure Votre préférence allant à « ce fut » indique que vous considérez « c'est » comme étant l'élision de « ce est ». Il me semble alors qu'il n'y a aucune raison de transformer ce « ce » en « ça » au passé composé.

Comment: @Édouard je crois que je ne suis pas claire dans ma réponse à ton commentaire. Je pense que le fait qu'il y ait si peu d’occurrences de « ç'a été » (par rapport à « ça a été » beaucoup plus répandu) ne vient pas seulement du fait qu'on préfère « ce fut » mais aussi que le « ce » « c'est » n'est pas rendu ce (ç) dans le passage au passé composé. Je n'ai pas trouvé d'explication, peut-être question euphonie ?

Comment: @jlliagre. Voir ma réponse à Édouard. Et la préférence pour ce fut, n'est pas une lubie, je l'ai déjà lue.

Comment: Je n'ai pas écrit que c'était une lubie, simplement qu'il y avait un contradiction dans votre réponse. D'ailleurs, on dit beaucoup plus « ce n'est pas » que « ça n'est pas ».

Answer (score 2):

Nous ne pouvons pas toujours remplacer le "ce" par "ça" ou "cela". Cette "solution" ne marche pas dans le cas général du présentatif.

Prenons la phrase: "C'est Pierre le coupable de notre retard".  Il est évident que nous ne pouvons pas remplacer ce "Ce"  pour "Ça" ni pour "Cela". Nous ne pouvons dire "Ça est Pierre le coupable de notre retard" ni "Cela est Pierre le coupable de notre retard". Alors, comment mettre la phrase "C'est Pierre le coupable de notre retard" au passé composé?

Que je sache, il y a deux solutions seulement:

1. "Ç'a été Pierre le coupable de notre retard", où le "Ç'a" est le résultat de l'élision de "Ce a". Le "Ç'", dans ce cas, n'est pas une forme de "ça" ni de "cela".
2. Tout simplement éviter le passé composé dans ce cas et préférer le passé simple: "Ce fut Pierre le coupable de notre retard".