# Peut-on dire ou écrire « ç'a été » ?

Tags: usage, orthographe

De manière informelle, on dit ou écrit fréquemment « ça a été ». Sans débattre de la justesse de cette locution, et vu qu'il y a une répétition du « a », peut on abréger en « ç'a été » ?

Exemple de contexte, tant à l'écrit qu'à l'oral :
- « Alors, ton examen... ça a été ? »
- « Oui, ç'a été. »

Comment: Merci @StéphaneGimenez mais non merci. Ce n'est pas un doublon. Votre réponse sur la question que vous croyez être un doublon ne répond pas à *ma* question. C'est pas possible le nombre de personne qui ont le click "doublon" facile sans prendre la peine de bien comprendre les différentes questions et de vérifier que les réponses répondent correctement à tout. La nuance ? Connais pô !

Comment: Sans débattre de la clarté de ta question, ta question n'est pas claire. J'ai préféré laisser un lien vers une autre question qui répond au moins au titre de celle-ci, plutôt que de clôre Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Prière de le dire alors. Et puis nous n'avons pas élevé les cochons ensemble, alors pas de tutoiement, surtout quand il y un "vous" de politesse juste au-dessus.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez (suite à votre édition) Cela semble suffisamment clair pour avoir une réponse qui répond très précisément et de maniète tout à fait correcte à la question.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Stéphane au sujet du doublon. Même avec l'édition, je vois mal de quelle nuance vous parlez. Veuillez étoffer votre question pour rendre dite nuance plus claire. Voulez-vous savoir si l'un est préférable à l'autre? Des références concrètes? Ou simplement ce qui est le plus commun? Dans le doublon, il est clair que les deux sont possibles, alors votre exemple serait correct tel qu'il est.

Comment: Je ne comprends tojours pas l'intêret. « Ç'a été » est de lui-même correct (cf. réponses à l'autre question). La question serait donc de savoir si on peut considérer que c'est aussi une version courte de « ça a été » ?… Ou bien est-ce de savoir si on peut l'utiliser à l'oral sans que ça passe pour du style littéraire ? Dans ce dernier cas il faut vraiment être plus clair.

Comment: C'est vous qui créez le flou : où ai-je parlé de littéraire ? J'ai écrit "informel", il me semble.

Comment: Vous ne vous aidez pas ici, en plantant les pieds. On veut bien vous aider, mais on ne comprend pas ce que vous demandez. Politique du site veut que l'on ferme jusqu'à éclaircissement. Alors prière d'expliquer au lieu de taper sur le messager. Si on parle en contexte informel et que l'on ne se préoccupe pas de la justesse, alors on peut dire ce que l'on veut? Encore une fois, quelle est la question, précisément?

Comment: [Les réponses](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9320/cest-in-pass%c3%a9-compos%c3%a9) signalées par @StéphaneGimenez donne la réponse à la question telle qu'elle est posée.

Answer (score 4):

Normalement non, bien que ce ne soit *pas formellement incorrect*, *ça a été* est beaucoup mieux.

On entend bien le "a" du verbe quand on le prononce.

Dans l'autre, on a l'impression d'entendre quelqu'un qui parle trop vite, pour une expression qui devrait normalement avoir un registre de langue élevé, c'est un comble.

Mais pour c’eût été, c'est différent, là c'est une vraie élision. Le "ça eût été" n'est pas joli.

Le site suivant, donne beaucoup d'élisions, mais certaines sont tellement tellement rares, qu'elles paraissent vraiment trop artificielles.

> ç'a été, ç'ont été (rare), ç'avaient été, ç'aura été, ç'auront
>   été,ç'aurait été, ç'auraient été, ç'eût été, ç'eussent été

http://orthonet.sdv.fr/php/rech_mot.php?mot=z%E9e

Autre source: http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%A7a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-%C3%A7a-a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-%C3%A9lision-de-ce-et-%C3%A7a.157982/?hl=fr

Donc je pense que c'est possible, car non interdit, mais pas trop souhaitable. Ensuite, ça dépend de l'effet de style qu'on veut faire. C'est dans quel contexte? Juste par curiosité?

Comment: Le contexte est les discussions entre connaissances proches (famille, amis, d'où le niveau "informel"). Exemple "alors, ton examen... ç'a été ?" - "oui, ç'a été" -- le tout tant à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

Comment: Seule la rareté de l'emploi rend cette expression un peu surprenante vue écrite, on a l'impression qu'il y a une faute, mais en fait, il ne semble pas que ce soit le cas. ça semble un contexte beaucoup plus familier ici, donc pourquoi pas, étant donné qu'on ne peut pas dire que ce soit faux. En fin de phrase, ça sonne quand même mieux, on a tous dû l'entendre.

Answer (score 1):

C'est à éviter.

On peut utiliser `ce fut`, au lieu de  `ça a été`.

Petit plus:

```
imparfait : "c'était"
passé simple : "ce fut"
passé composé : "ça a été"
plus que parfait : "ça avait été" ("ç'avait été" en parler rapide, mais ce n'est pas très beau)
passé antérieur : "c'eut été"
futur antérieur" : "ça aura été" ("ç'aura été" en parler rapide, mais ce n'est pas très beau non plus)
```

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question et va même là où je ne voulais pas aller : "Sans débattre de la justesse de cette locution".