# « Ç'a été » et « Ça a été »

Tags: orthographe, démonstratifs

Considérons les phrases :

> « Ça a été difficile ».
>
> « Ç'a été difficile ».

Les deux phrases sont-elles équivalentes ? Moi je pense non puisqu'au présent elles seraient (je crois)

> Ça (=cela) est difficile.
>
> C'est difficile.

Laquelle est la plus correcte ? Laquelle serait la plus courante ?

Comment: Quand tu entends « Ç'a été difficile », est-tu sûr de ne pas entendre « Ça était » ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak J' en suis sur car je l'ai rencontré dans un livre et puis il y a d'autres questions posées dans FSE. J'espère que ma question n'est pas un doublon:-)!

Comment: @LukeSawczak Voir ici p. ex. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23594/peut-on-dire-ou-%C3%A9crire-%C3%A7a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9

Comment: Tant de nouvelles choses pour moi cette semaine lol !

Comment: @LukeSawczak Je ne sais pas s'il y a quelqu'un qui peut prétendre maîtriser la langue française :-)! http://jactiv.ouest-france.fr/actualites/culture/10-plus-belles-fautes-francais-nos-grands-ecrivains-58682

Comment: lol à la faute de Balzac ! Je suis du genre pourtant qui préfère imaginer qu'il y a des écrivains qui puissent nous être un exemple parfait, malavisé que ça soit ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak *lol La faute à Balzac ! Je suis pourtant du genre qui préfère imaginer qu'il y a des écrivains qui pourraient nous être des exemples parfaits, aussi inconsidéré que ce soit.* ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La première phrase est d'un registre familier puisque *ça* est utilisé pour *cela* :

> Ça a été difficile. (Cela a été difficile, cela fut difficile)

La deuxième phrase est soit d'un registre encore plus familier si l'on considère qu'il y a élision du *a* de *ça* qui n'est normalement pas marquée à l'écrit.

> Ç'a été difficile.

Cette même phrase peut en revanche être comprise comme d'un registre plus soutenu si le *ç'* correspond à l'élision du pronom *ce*:

> Ç'a été difficile. (Ce fut difficile)

Voici un exemple littéraire de ce deuxième type d'élision :

> Si vous aviez peur de le manquer, ce train au mouvement et au bruit duquel vous êtes maintenant déjà réhabitué, ce n'est pas que vous vous soyez réveillé ce matin plus tard que vous l'aviez prévu, puisque, bien au contraire, votre premier mouvement, comme vous ouvriez les yeux, **ç'a été** d'étendre le bras pour empêcher que se déclenche la sonnerie, tandis que l'aube commençait à sculpter les draps en désordre de votre lit, les draps qui émergeaient de l'obscurité semblables à des fantômes vaincus, écrasés au ras de ce sol mou et chaud dont vous cherchiez à vous arracher. *La Modification*, Michel Butor, 1957

Comment: @jiliagre Il semble que vous vous mépreniez:  « Ce a été difficile; » ne se dit pas; (« Ce fut difficile. » se dit et est équivalent bien que dans un autre registre.). « Ç'a a été difficile » ne peut être que l'orthographe de la contraction « Ça a  été... » dans la langue parlée.

Comment: @user168676 Oui, *ce a* ne se dit pas et c'est bien mon propos. L'élision s'impose et donne *ç'a*...

Comment: @ jiliagre Je ne comprends pas, par « Cette même phrase peut en revanche être comprise comme d'un registre plus soutenu si le ç correspond à l'élision du pronom ce:    Ç'a été difficile. (Ce fut difficile) » vous affirmez expliquer que « ce  a » n'existe pas alors que cela dit qu'il y a la possibilité de cette interprétation dans un registre plus élevé? Pour pouvoir considérer une possible interprétation  en tant qu'une forme donnée il faut d'abord reconnaitre que cette forme existe.

Comment: @user168676 Quand j'écris *ce a* ne se dit pas, ça veut dire que la forme non élidée ne se dit pas, comme *la amitié* ne se dit pas. Ça ne veut pas dire que *l'amitié* ou *ç'a* ne se disent pas. *Ce* devient *c'* devant *e* et devient *ç'* devant *a*. C'est indiqué dans tous les bon dictionnaires.

Comment: @ jlliagre Je vois, la forme élidée pour « la amitié » est « l'amitié », je suis d'accord; de façon analogique vous dites que « ç'a » dans certain cas serait la forme de remplacement pour « ce a » qui n'existe pas; pourquoi elle n'existerait pas alors que « ça a » existe; cependant ce n'est pas le résultat d'une élision. Il n'y a aucune preuve de l'existence de votre « c'e » en tant que remplacement de « ce a »; cette forme est un complet fantome dans dans votre appréhension du langage, et vous en faites « ce a » quand vous le voulez! Je suis désolé d'avoir à dire que c'est ma façon de voir.

Comment: @user168676 Pourquoi *ça a* existe ? Parce que *ça* ne s'élide pas à l'écrit devant *a*, c'est une règle du français. Voir par exemple le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a) ou tout autre dictionnaire qui se respecte. En revanche, *ç'a* n'est pas un fantôme d'une appréhension personnelle, mais est attesté dans la littérature et documenté dans [Le Bon usage (Grevisse)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) et autres grammaires et dictionnaires, par exemple le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce).

Comment: @jlliagreReprenons le cas des formes de remplacement: lorsque l'on trouve « l'amitié » on sait que parce qu'il n'y qu'une possibilité de mot directement avant « amitié » qui puisse être transformé en « l'» et ce mot est toujours « la » qu'il s'agit de « la »; mais lorsque il s'agit de « ç'a » comment sait-on quel était le choix de l'auteur? Il n'y a aucun moyen de le savoir (c'est pourquoi je dis "fantome"). Il existerais alors dans le langage une forme qui est laissée à la libre interprétation du lecteur, ce qui est aberrant.

Comment: @user168676 La seule forme acceptable dans un ouvrage littéraire écrit en français soutenu est une élision de *ce a* qui est documentée et obligatoire. L'élision optionnelle du français parlé *ça a* qui ne peut être marquée à l'écrit d'après les règles de grammaire française, n'est pas concevable dans l'extrait que j'ai ajouté à ma réponse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82104/discussion-between-user168676-and-jlliagre).