# Google Translate: C'est vs. Ç'est

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, participe-présent, pronoms-impersonnels

Google Translate keeps correcting my inputs any time I attempt to translate a sentence containing *«**c**'est»* by suggesting I put *«**ç**'est»* instead.

Is this contraction even correct (because I've been studying French via Duolingo for two years now and I've never seen it appear)? If not, how is it even possible that they're suggesting this since the software itself is based on AI models trained on volumes and volumes of native literature? Could it be that *«ç'est»* is a deprecated form of *«c'est»*?

Comment: `ç` doesn't exist before `e` and `i` even with apostrophe between.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Ç'est" is totally impossible in French!

Comment: Ç'est vrai ! J'upvote ;-)

Answer (score 8):

**Ç'est** is not correct French. Even a Text Editor recognizes this.
On the contrary

> Ça a été difficile; Ç'a été difficile.

are both correct. See the relevant discussion here: [« Ç'a été » et « Ça a été »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/%C3%87a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-vs-%C3%87a-a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9)

and the response of @[jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/%C3%87a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-vs-%C3%87a-a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9/31057#31057) therein.