# C'est beau, la vie!

Tags: pronoms, accord

I have just heard the following sentence in the movie "Le Fabuleux Destin de Amélie Poulain":

> C'est beau, la vie.

I have found out that there is also a [song with this name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hhv-PSDpxg).

Shouldn't "beau" agree with the feminine noun "vie" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Beau/belle" must agree with "ce", written "c'" in this locution; as the gender of "ce" is neuter, the form of the adjective must be "beau", the masculine form and also the form for the neuter gender.

Comment: I'm really confused now. I thought that c' was an ellision of "ça", the *neutral* indefinite pronom.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista You'll find the confirmation and plenty od examples here:https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce. Apparently this elision for "ça" does not exist: (ça a marché) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=19&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&content=%C3%A7a+a&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20a%3B%2Cc0 https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a

Comment: See also this [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31049/%c3%87a-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-et-%c3%87a-a-%c3%a9t%c3%a9/31057#31057) and [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82104/discussion-between-user168676-and-jlliagre)...

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: Consider that the negation of such phrases is "ce n'est pas" and not "ça n'est pas". I need to double-check, but there should be a difference between "ce" as a sort of dummy pronoun and "ce" as a demonstrative adjective. LPH: That's in keeping with my understanding of French, but I did see a text recently where the author wrote things like "ç'avait."

Comment: @Maroon En effet, on trouve cette forme, mais elle est trompeuse (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7%27avait&corpus=19&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A7%27avait%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A7'avait%3B%2Cc0); voir cette référence: https://books.google.fr/books?id=fT1kAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA66&dq=%22%C3%A7%27avait%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiK1IGt8c7rAhXJnKQKHdMBDocQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A7'avait%22&f=false; (1/2)

Comment: @Maroon vous remarquerez que lorsqu'il s'agit d'une consonne initiale pour la forme verbale on ne trouve pas « ça » mais « ce ». Le fin mot de l'histoire est que « ç'avait » est l'abréviation de « ce avait », ou pour parler proprement, « ç' » est la forme graphique (et phonétique) que prend « ce » suivi d'un verbe commençant par « a » ou « e »; je suspecte que "c'est" n'est pas autre chose que « ç'est ", lequel on trouve dans la littérature ancienne. (2/2)

Comment: Merci, vous avez raison. J'ai compris le sens du syntagme sans avoir une connaissance de son analyse grammaticale.